# CloudFormation Rules for StepFunctions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I have used CloudFormation to create CloudWatch event rules and associated permissions to run lambdas, but I can't find similar documentation for starting Step Function executions. For example, if the following is correct for lambdas, what is the analog for Step Functions?

```
"ExecuteLambda1" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::Events::Rule",
            "Properties" : {
                "Name" : "rule-1",
                "Description" : "Run Lambda1",
                "ScheduleExpression": "rate(15 minutes)",
                "State": "DISABLED",
                "Targets": [{
                    "Arn": "arn:Lambda1Arn",
                    "Id": "Lambda1Arn1"
                }]
            }
        },
        "PermissionForExecuteLambda1": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Properties": {
                "FunctionName": "arn:Lambda1Arn",
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["ExecuteLambda1", "Arn"] }
            }
        }
```

I assume you need to change "FunctionName" to point to the Step Function, and the "Action" to "StartExecution," but my attempts at guessing didn't work out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a role with permissions to start your step function and then use that role under `ExecuteLambda1`->`Properties`->`Targets[0]`->`RoleArn`?